# ReactJs / Flex-box justify between on multiples of three

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css

It seems like every time I start to think I get a grasp on flex-box, I end up trying to create something that I cannot seem to figure out. I have a section on my website where I want users to be able to upload images dynamically. I have the React working for this component so that once an image is uploaded, the option to upload a new one appears. I was planning on spreading 3 images through the container and wrapping once more images were added. In order to do this, I am using a flex row with flex-wrap and justify-between (to align on the edges).

The issue I am having is upon having a number in between the desired number per row (e.g. 2, 5, 8, ...), the justify between causes the items to split across the container. This is clearly not the desired behavior, but I've struggled for the past few hours to fix it and was hoping to get some guidance.

In an attempt to solve the problem I tried using CSS Grid, but was unable to get the desired behavior, often times just having the elements all align to the start of their respective grid cell and I was unable to find a fix for this.

I feel like this should be doable with pure CSS, but I'd love to be shown otherwise regardless!

This is an example of the behavior I am currently getting:

[image: Screenshot of two separated images]

as well as an image of the issue of flex-grid not aligning items in columns as desired (left, center, right).
[image: Image of CSS grid issue]

And the snippet of my code with the issue is:

```
    <div className="w-full">
        <div className="w-full flex flex-wrap justify-between">
            {images.map((imageUrl, index) => (
                <ImageUpload /> {* Used to display existing uploaded images *}
            ))}
            <ImageUpload /> {* Used as a new upload element *}
        </div>
    </div>
```

A CodePen can also be viewed here: https://codepen.io/developerryan/pen/GRWYKOm

Comment: Please create a short & simple working fiddle with placeholder images to demonstrate the issue. The code provided is not enough imo.

Comment: I think this should be doable with CSS grid.... so you basically need a 3 column layout in which the images should take all the width available in their respective column and the rows should be based on the number of images?

Comment: @Akash I think that sounds correct. I am unable to get this to work with the flex-box with the image however. When I set `w-full` it simply collapses the container for some reason.

Comment: I've gone ahead and created a Codepen here: https://codepen.io/developerryan/pen/GRWYKOm @Mr_Green

Answer (score 0):

We can use gridbox to the parent element which has the images in it. Something like this:

```
.parent-element {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 150px);
}
```

```css
.parent-element {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 150px);
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="w-full p-4">
  <div class="flex flex-col w-full h-full justify-between bg-gray-100">
    <div class="parent-element w-full flex flex-wrap justify-between">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x250" w="150" h="250" />
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x250" w="150" h="250" />
      <!--  Add images to see how it changes  -->
      <!--  Ideal behavior is to have 2 items space similar to 3 with 2nd item sit where the second does with 3 items -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```